# Tables in IEEE journal

Tags: tables, ieee-style

Here is the [template](https://ieeecs-media.computer.org/assets/tar/ieeetran-final_sub.tar) I use for the following 
[journal](https://www.computer.org/csdl/journal/tk/write-for-us/15073?title=Author%20Information&periodical=IEEE%20Transactions%20on%20Knowledge%20%26%20Data%20Engineering).
I have problems with all the tables that are perfect in regular latex document.
Here is the page with all the tables:

[image]

Here is the packages I added and the tables:

```
% *** MATH PACKAGES ***
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\newcommand{\tvar}[2]{%
    \mathrm{#1}_{\mathrm{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{0.6\columnwidth}{@{}c L S[table-format=7.0]*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]}@{}}
        \toprule
        \thead{ID}  &   \thead{UCI Dataset Name} 
        &   {\thead{Samples}}
        &   {\thead{Attributes}} 
        &   {\thead{Classes}}           \\
        \midrule
        DS2 & \textbf {Pfsddfs}- cdfsads dfsdffdss                      & 2222222  & 22    & 5     \\
        DS2 & \textbf {ESSSS} - cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss 
        & 45555  & 9    & 2     \\
        DS3 & \textbf {AAAA} -  cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss  & 22222  & 54     & 7     \\
        DS4 & \textbf {ABBB} - cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss    & 539383  & 28    & 2    \\
        DS5 & \textbf {SSSS}                                & 60000 &  3 & 3       \\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Ssdfsdfsddgs dgfgdsg gsdgsfggdfsfgd sdfgfgsd}
    \label{table:2}
\end{table}

    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=2.3, table-number-alignment=center, tight-spacing,}% table-column-width =2.5cm 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \small
    \centering

    \sisetup{detect-weight,mode=text}
    \renewrobustcmd{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
    \renewrobustcmd{\boldmath}{}
    % abbreviation
    \newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}
    % shorten the intercolumn spaces
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{l>{\centering}lSSSS}
        \toprule

        \thead {Dataset \\ Name}  & {\thead{No. of processed \\ records} }& {\thead{fsad fsd Trfsdee\\ Acc }} & {\thead{fsdd\\ Acc} }
        & {\thead{dfsadf Alg\\Acc} } & {\thead{dfsfds fsd\\ J48}} \\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        Pfds fssdf & 200K to 900K & 0.504 & 0.504 & \B 0.504  & 0.504 \\
        Pfds fssd & 200K to 900K & 0.524 & \B 0.546 & \B 0.546  & 0.498\\
        dfsfs     & 200K to 900K & 0.504 & \B0.832   & \B 0.504 & 0.504 \\
        fssdf     & 200K to 900K & 0.504 & \B0.754   & \B 0.754& 0.702 \\ 
        Codsffdspe  & 200K to 900K & 0.622 & 0.504 & \B 0.504 & 0.676 \\ 
        Codsffdspe & 200K to 900K & 0.563 &  \B0.674 & 0.665 & 0.686 \\ 
        sdfdf  & 200K to 900K & 0.956 & \B 0.957 & 0.956 & 0.945\\
        sdfdf  & 200K to 900K & 0.949 & \B0.504 & \B 0.955 & 0.952\\
        dsa  & 20K to 90K       & 0.895 &  0.798 & \B 0.504 & 0.853\\
        dsa  & 20K to 90K    & 0.924 & 0.834 & \B 0.932
        & 0.927\\
        dsa-2  & 20K to 90K       & 0.899 &  0.906 & \B 0.943 & 0.942\\
        SdsaA-2  & 20K to 90K       & 0.892 &  \B0.947 & \B 0.947 & 0.942\\
        SEdsaA-3  & 20K to 90K       &  0.884 &  0.832 & \B 0.897 & 0.846\\
        [2ex]
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Csdfdfsdfs  CsdfdfsdfsCsdfdfsdfsCsdfdfsdfsCsdfdfsdfs)}
    \label{table:2a}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=2.3, table-number-alignment=center, tight-spacing,}% table-column-width =2.5cm 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \small
    \centering

    \sisetup{detect-weight,mode=text}
    \renewrobustcmd{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
    \renewrobustcmd{\boldmath}{}
    % abbreviation
    \newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}
    % shorten the intercolumn spaces
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{l>{\centering}lSSSS}
        \toprule

        \thead {Dataset \\ Name}  & {\thead{fsddsf \\ records} }& {\thead{Hsfd\\ Acc }} & {\thead{fsdsf\\ Acc} }
        & {\thead{sfdfsd sfdf\\Acc} } & {\thead{fsd fs\\ fsd}} \\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        fsdfs fsd & 100K to 900K & 0.504 & 0.547 & \B 0.548  & 0.503 \\
        fsdfs fsd & 200K to 900K & 0.524 &  0.548 & \B 0.550  & 0.498\\
        sfddfs& 200K to 900K & 0.788 & \B0.833   & 0.832 & 0.824 \\
        fddfs& 200K to 900K & 0.680 & 0.757   & \B 0.758& 0.702 \\ 
        Cosdfype  & 200K to 900K & 0.622 & 0.735 & \B 0.735 & 0.676 \\ 
        Cdfspe & 200K to 900K & 0.563 &  0.677 & \B 0.678 & 0.686 \\ 
        Airfsd  & 200K to 900K & 0.956 &  0.959 & \B 0.962 & 0.945\\
        dfsf  & 200K to 500K & 0.949 & \B0.958 & \B 0.958 & 0.952\\
        SfdsEA  & 20K to 90K & 0.895 &  0.802 & \B 0.899 & 0.853\\
        SEfdsA  & 20K to 90K    & 0.924 & 0.836 & \B 0.934 & 0.927\\
        fds-2  & 20K to 90K       & 0.899 &  0.935 & \B 0.943 & 0.942\\
        fds-2  & 20K to 90K       & 0.892 &  0.952 & \B 0.954 & 0.942\\
        Sfds3  & 20K to 90K       &  0.884 &  0.853 & \B 0.897 & 0.846\\
        [2ex]
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{fgdfgdsgsf (In \textbf{Bold} thedfgsdfggf)}
    \label{table:2b}
\end{table} 

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=2.3, table-number-alignment=center, tight-spacing,}% table-column-width =2.5cm 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \small
    \centering

    \sisetup{detect-weight,mode=text}
    \renewrobustcmd{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
    \renewrobustcmd{\boldmath}{}
    % abbreviation
    \newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}
    % shorten the intercolumn spaces
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular} {l c c} %{l>{\centering}lSSSS}
        \toprule

        \thead {Dataset \\ Name}  & {\thead{dsaasd add dada (sec) \\ 1000 dsad} } & {\thead{adsdas das ddsa Time (sec) \\ 2000 fdsfds}} \\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
        dfg gdfs & 22.222 & 4.4222\\
        sdfgg& 22.222 &  4.0222 \\
        sdfggsd  & 22.222  & 22.2226\\ 
        dsfggfd  & 32.355 & 2.277 \\ 
        dfd  & 20.254 & 2.238 \\ 
        [2ex]
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    %    \end{tabular}
    \caption{fgdfgsd}
    \label{table:3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please describe the output you expect? Do you want your tables to appear as if you used a onecolumn documentclass?

Comment: If so, use `table*` instead of `table` for all tables,  and `\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}` instead of `\begin{tabularx}{0.6\columnwidth}` for the first table.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you might want to consider using some carefulle placed `\phantom{0}` commands in order to improve the alignment of the second column of your second and third table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off-topic:

- In your MWE is missed document class. For my MWE I use `IEEEtran`.
- From your preamble I considered only packages relevant to your tables (other I remove from my MWE, however check again, if you really need all those packages and if some of them are loaded twice).
- If article is intended to some IEEE journal, don't reformat their default settings for caption etc.

Tables:

- I suggest move all new command definition from tables to preamble (for example `\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}`.
- Remove all repeated settings from table (for example `\centering`, `\tabcolsep` etc).
- It is not clear why the width of the first table selected is much smaller than the width of the column.
- In MWE below I clean-up table codes and and tried to design them in a uniform way.

Your problem:

- It is not clear (to me), what is your problem. Table design?

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{amsmath} is supersede by mathtools, 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \small
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \caption{Ssdfsdfsddgs dgfgdsg gsdgsfggdfsfgd sdfgfgsd}
    \label{table:2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c L S[table-format=7.0]*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]} @{}}
        \toprule
\thead{ID}  & \thead{UCI Dataset Name} & {\thead{Samples}} & {\thead{Attributes}} & {\thead{Classes}}\\
         \midrule
        DS2 & \textbf{Pfsddfs}- cdfsads dfsdffdss                      & 2222222  & 22    & 5     \\
        DS2 & \textbf{ESSSS} - cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss
        & 45555  & 9    & 2     \\
        DS3 & \textbf{AAAA} -  cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss  & 22222  & 54     & 7     \\
        DS4 & \textbf{ABBB} - cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss cdfsads dfsdffdss    & 539383  & 28    & 2    \\
        DS5 & \textbf{SSSS}                                & 60000 &  3 & 3       \\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \sisetup{detect-weight,
             mode=text,
             table-format=2.3}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \caption{Csdfdfsdfs  Csdfdf sdfsCsdf dfsdfs CsdfdfsdfsCs dfdfsdfs)}
    \label{table:2a}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l c SSSS}
        \toprule
    \thead[b]{Dataset \\ Name}  
        & {\thead[b]{No. of\\ processed \\ records} }
            & {\thead[b]{fsad fsd\\ Trfsdee\\ Acc }} 
                & {\thead[b]{fsdd\\ Acc} }
                    & {\thead[b]{dfsadf\\ Alg\\Acc} } 
                        & {\thead[b]{dfsfds fsd\\ J48}} \\ 
        \midrule
        Pfds fssdf & 200K to 900K & 0.504 & 0.504    & \B 0.504 & 0.504 \\
        Pfds fssd  & 200K to 900K & 0.524 & \B 0.546 & \B 0.546 & 0.498 \\
        dfsfs      & 200K to 900K & 0.504 & \B 0.832 & \B 0.504 & 0.504 \\
        fssdf      & 200K to 900K & 0.504 & \B 0.754 & \B 0.754 & 0.702 \\
        Codsffdspe & 200K to 900K & 0.622 &    0.504 & \B 0.504 & 0.676 \\
        Codsffdspe & 200K to 900K & 0.563 & \B 0.674 &    0.665 & 0.686 \\
        sdfdf      & 200K to 900K & 0.956 & \B 0.957 &    0.956 & 0.945 \\
        sdfdf      & 200K to 900K & 0.949 & \B 0.504 & \B 0.955 & 0.952 \\
        dsa        & 20K to 90K   & 0.895 &    0.798 & \B 0.504 & 0.853 \\
        dsa        & 20K to 90K   & 0.924 &    0.834 & \B 0.932 & 0.927 \\
        dsa-2      & 20K to 90K   & 0.899 &    0.906 & \B 0.943 & 0.942 \\
        SdsaA-2    & 20K to 90K   & 0.892 & \B 0.947 & \B 0.947 & 0.942 \\
        SEdsaA-3   & 20K to 90K   & 0.884 &    0.832 & \B 0.897 & 0.846 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \sisetup{table-format=2.3, 
             detect-weight,
             mode=text}% table-column-width =2.5cm
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \small
\caption{fgdfgdsgsf (In \textbf{Bold} thedfgsdfggf)}
\label{table:2b}
     \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l c SSSS}
        \toprule
\thead {Dataset \\ Name}  
    & {\thead{fsddsf \\ records} }
        & {\thead{Hsfd\\ Acc }} 
            & {\thead{fsdsf\\ Acc} }
                & {\thead{sfdfsd sfdf\\Acc} } 
                    & {\thead{fsd fs\\ fsd}} \\ [0.5ex]
        \midrule
fsdfs fsd & 100K to 900K & 0.504 &    0.547 & \B 0.548 & 0.503 \\
fsdfs fsd & 200K to 900K & 0.524 &    0.548 & \B 0.550 & 0.498 \\
sfddfs    & 200K to 900K & 0.788 & \B 0.833 &    0.832 & 0.824 \\
fddfs     & 200K to 900K & 0.680 &    0.757 & \B 0.758 & 0.702 \\
Cosdfype  & 200K to 900K & 0.622 &    0.735 & \B 0.735 & 0.676 \\
Cdfspe    & 200K to 900K & 0.563 &    0.677 & \B 0.678 & 0.686 \\
Airfsd    & 200K to 900K & 0.956 &    0.959 & \B 0.962 & 0.945 \\
dfsf      & 200K to 500K & 0.949 & \B 0.958 & \B 0.958 & 0.952 \\
SfdsEA    & 20K to 90K   & 0.895 &    0.802 & \B 0.899 & 0.853 \\
SEfdsA    & 20K to 90K   & 0.924 &    0.836 & \B 0.934 & 0.927 \\
fds-2     & 20K to 90K   & 0.899 &    0.935 & \B 0.943 & 0.942 \\
fds-2     & 20K to 90K   & 0.892 &    0.952 & \B 0.954 & 0.942 \\
Sfds3     & 20K to 90K   & 0.884 &    0.853 & \B 0.897 & 0.846 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{fgdfgsd}
    \label{table:3}
    \sisetup{table-format=2.4}% table-column-width =2.5cm
    \centering
    \small
    \begin{tabular} {l S S } 
        \toprule
\thead {Dataset \\ Name}  
    & {\thead{dsaasd add dada (sec) \\ 1000 dsad} } 
        & {\thead{adsdas das ddsa Time (sec) \\ 2000 fdsfds}} \\
    \midrule
dfg gdfs & 22.222 &  4.4222 \\
sdfgg    & 22.222 &  4.0222 \\
sdfggsd  & 22.222 & 22.2226 \\
dsfggfd  & 32.355 &  2.277  \\
dfd      & 20.254 &  2.238  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]